# Qualify Class Properties During/After Constructor (Sub New)

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking for a way to get the value of a property during or after the New() sub. In general though I would like to know if there is a way to call some code automatically after a class has **all** of its properties fully initiated.

During the Sub New() properties are set to their initial values, rather than the ones that are set up at design time.

Essentially I'm wondering if it's possible to setup something similar to the "Form Shown" event, except for classes.

Code:

```
Public Class Test
inherits Component

Public Event Initiated()

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
    RaiseEvent Initiated()
End Sub

Private Sub OnInitiated() Handles Me.Initiated
    Debug.WriteLine(Max)
End Sub

Private _Max As Integer = 5
Public Property Max() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Max
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        _Max = Value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Note: The value of the "Max" property is set to 3 in the design view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with using the constructor is that the designer code sets your properties well after it creates your object. But, the NET Framework includes the interface `ISupportInitialize` which is ideal for controls and components which need to do things such as qualify properties conditionally - for instance checking `Value` *after* `Min` and `Max` are set.

It is easy to use:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Test
    Inherits Component
    Implements ISupportInitialize
```

When you press enter on the last line, it will add 2 methods:

```
Public Sub BeginInit() Implements ISupportInitialize.BeginInit

Public Sub EndInit() Implements ISupportInitialize.EndInit
```

Which allows you to do this:

```
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub

Public Sub EndInit() Implements ISupportInitialize.EndInit
    ' do whatever you want to do
    ' all properties will be initialized at this time
    ' e.g. Max will be the IDE value, not 5
    ...
End Sub
```

The way it works is that VS will invoke this from the designer code after the control/component properties.  If you open the designer code you will see something like this:

```
 ' ctl declarations
 CType(Me.Test1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()

 ' lots of code initializing controls
 Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
 ...
 Me.Button1.Location = ...
 ...
 Me.Test1.Max = 3         ' yours will be there somewhere

 ' then at the end:
 CType(Me.Test1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
```

So, you can add any code you need to run before anything is created in your `BeginInit` method, and code you need to run *after* all properties are initialized in `EndInit`.

---

`BeginInit` and `EndInit` will run every time the designer code is run.  That is, every time at runtime and after there are enough changes to the form that it needs to be rebuilt.  You do need to keep your component code fresh since VS is using a compiled version of it in the IDE when working on the project using it.

So, Rebuild often and Clean when it seems like it is not picking up changes.

Comment: This is supposed to work in design mode and in the executable itself correct? For some reason the code I had setup there didn't display the first few times the program ran. Oddly enough, after rebuilding it another time it seems to work. 

I wonder what that is about, since I didn't change anything related to that after rebuilding...? 

Anyways, thank you very much!

Comment: it will run every time at runtime, and when the designer code is refreshed/rebuilt (for instance opening the form designer hosting your component); you can add `Console.Beep` to EndInit to get a feel.  If you make changes to the component, you will want to Rebuild and even Clean often to be sure VS is using the right code.

Comment: @MakoInfused there is also a event based version called `ISupportInitializeNotification` - note that either one can "trickle" down events or notices to sub objects to initialize stuff as well

Comment: Awesome thanks again, I really appreciate the thorough explanation. Yeah that's probably what it was then, just needed a clean/rebuild. I always forget about that. I'll need to delve more into the "Implements" statement.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could see to answer your question is to set up a custom event in your class and fire it at the end of the constructor

Comment: Good suggestion, I just tried that out. Unfortunately the event was still raised before the properties were initialized...

Comment: What do you mean by before the properties were initialized ? When are they initialized if not in the constructor ? Can you show your code ?

Comment: What I mean is in my second paragraph, the property still holds it's initial value. I'll update the post to include some pseudo-code. Thanks.

Comment: Is this a UserControl class ?

Comment: If you only have one property then you could try firing an event in the Set clause of the property. Else I guess you could either try to find out which is set up last and fire the event in this one or fire an event for each property and handle them separetly

Comment: That's a good work around, you've been very helpful-- thank you!