# Boolean property returns false at runtime despite being set to "true" via Designer

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Hopefully this has a simple fix:

I have created a custom textbox for my solution. To that custom control I added an auto property called "AllowEmpty":

```
Public Property AllowEmpty As Boolean
```

Both my constructor and event read that property's value and act accordingly:

```
Public Sub New()

    If AllowEmpty Then
        Text = String.Empty
    Else
        Text = "0"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CustomTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.TextChanged

    If AllowEmpty Then
        Text = String.Empty
    Else
        Text = "0"
    End If

End Sub
```

However by setting a breakpoint I see that if I set "AllowEmpty" to True on the Designer, it's still false at runtime. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting a default value directly in your auto-implemented property: `Public Property AllowEmpty As Boolean = True`

Comment: @AlexB. I don't quite understand why but by going to the Designer again after changing the code to the exact suggestion in the below answer and re-enforcing everything to True (and a few controls to False), it finally worked as expected, but not at construction time, when I get a "False" even in case of "True" and a "0" appears. I don't want this to happen, do you know a workaround?

Comment: I guess because the property values set in designer are not initialized in the constructor but in an overridable method. Please check if [InitializeNewComponent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171821.aspx) is the correct one.

Comment: They are initialized by the container's designer. But the container can't set properties of the control until it is constructed. Seems like a chicken / egg situation. I don't think it's possible to access them in the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order that things happen is not in your favor, if trying to access a design-time set custom property in the component's constructor.

Assuming this CustomTextBox is on Form1, here is what happens:

1. Form1 constructor
2. Form1 constructor calls `Form1.InitializeComponent()`
3. Inside InitializeComponent, `Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()`
4. CustomTextBox is constructed now
5. Back to `Form1.InitializeComponent()`

Then this code in InitializeComponent()

```
'CustomTextBox1
'
Me.CustomTextBox1.AllowEmpty = True ' <--- that is the designer set value
Me.CustomTextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
Me.CustomTextBox1.Name = "CustomTextBox1"
Me.CustomTextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
Me.CustomTextBox1.TabIndex = 0
' ...
```

As you can see, any designer set properties are set in code here, *after* the class is constructed. So the constructor is not the best place to access them.

But you can instead use `OnCreateControl`

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateControl()
    MyBase.OnCreateControl()
    If AllowEmpty Then
        Text = String.Empty
    Else
        Text = "0"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Originally it had been defined normally. Apparently by explictly placing parenthesis on the Set like that and re-enforcing all controls on Designer, this has been fixed, however when the constructor runs it still returns false, apparently because the control doesn't yet exist, causing a "0" to be displayed even if True. How can I avoid that?

Comment: I love you! You not only brilliantly answered this question but provided me with knowledge of this useful event I was not aware of, I could see myself having a lot less trouble with recent code I've written had I used it instead of a different approach. Thanks a ton.

Comment: If you have several properties and you need something to happen after all of them are set, `ISupportIntialize` is an interface that invokes a method after the ctor and after all properties are set  @Renato

Comment: @Plutonix Could you please provide me a basic example of the usage (other than documentation)? I learn better that way. Thanks

Comment: In addition to inheriting TextBox, your component should also have `Implements ISupportInitialize`. Implement the interface and it will create `BeginInit` and `EndInit` methods. When adding to a container, the designer code will include both calls as @Plutonix mentioned. Then you would put the logic in `EndInit` instead of `OnCreateControl`.

Comment: @djv Is using `ISupportInitialize` over `OnCreateControl` best in what kind of scenario? Or better, what does one do that the other doesn't? I am curious.

Comment: @Renato see [Qualify Class Properties During/After Constructor (Sub New)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26291401/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix shameless self promotion (jk you got my vote :P )... The interface seems like the designer had an intention to support what we are doing here. But, I'm not sure how this application would differ if you use one or the other.

Comment: The interface is more for cases where you have to consider multiple properties to set something up after the ctor.  OnCreateControl is going to run after the ctor but before the properties are set, I think.  The other pitfall is that properties are serialized in alphabetical order and properties with default values arent serialized at all, so hooking into setters can be a problem.

Comment: @Plutonix I am trying to overload `EndInit` which is already on an inheriting `CustomErrorProvider`, but the code in there isn't even hitting the breakpoint. Why is that? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a new question...but you cant overload the method it wont compile if you try passing parameters.  The link explains other dynamics involving the designer code at both runtime and possibly design time

Comment: @Plutonix It was what felt like a minor appendix so I added it as a comment instead of creating a whole question just for that. I was forgetting to add `Implements ISupportInitialize.EndInit` on the method signature as well. Now working as intended!